# Stop reading a file in awk after a particular sequence of characters is encountered

Tags: windows, awk

I wish to stop reading the input file after ") ;" is encountered. 
I am reading all files from a folder (using a batch file) and the script is working on each of the file.

How to do it?

Comment: See [ask] then try again.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
awk '/);/{nextfile}'
```

- `nextfile`: Stop  processing  the  current input file, and go to next file

Comment: Note that `nextfile` is a GNU awk extension - requires `gawk`.